# Installing nvm and other git things keeps giving permission denied, either as root or not

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, nvm

On WSL/Ubuntu. 
I had a previous hard drive that went missing, recovered, put back into system (not modified), the I changed some directories, now permissions issues are popping up. The main user/bash directory is on this hard drive (/mnt/d/unix).

I'm trying to reinstall nvm completely, but it's giving this permissions error (same whether I run as root or any other user):

```
rw3iss@ryspace:/mnt/c/Users/rw3iss$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13527  100 13527    0     0   101k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  101k
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/mnt/d/unix/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/mnt/d/unix/.nvm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 290, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (290/290), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (257/257), done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/mnt/d/unix/.nvm/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!
rw3iss@ryspace:/mnt/c/Users/rw3iss$
```

I've tried a bunch of things, cleared out all my .bash_profile stuff related to nvm, nvm completely off system, reinstalled node from scratch.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to clear these issues up?